# how to parse JSONArray in android as of following data

Tags: arrays, json, json-api

**JSON**

[image: data]

I would like to know how to parse the data shown above in a class named as ***forecast.java***

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONArray cast = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("abridged_cast");
 for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject actor = cast.getJSONObject(i);
 String name = actor.getString("name");
 allNames.add(name);
}
```

(typed straight into the browser, so not tested).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Forecast Class Model and parse it with `GSON` like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Forecast> allForecasts = new ArrayList<Forecast>();

JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(jsonResponse));
reader.setLenient(true);

Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Forecast>>(){}.getType();
allForecasts = gson.fromJson(reader, collectionType);

Log.i("allForecasts ", allForecasts.get(0).getForecast()get(0).getDate());
```